# Reading a Java Regular Expressions Script

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning Java regular expressions from this site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

And I'm having a hard time trying to come up with the reading output for most of the examples on that page/how the input is solved. Is m.group(0) referring to (.*) and m.group(1) to (\d+) etc?

for example:
Input:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
public static void main( String args[] ){

  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
  String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
Found value: This order was placed for QT300
Found value: 0
```

As well as the start and end Methods, for this one I'm not sure what the .start, .end are doing:

Input:

```
public class RegexMatches
{
    private static final String REGEX = "\\bcat\\b";
    private static final String INPUT =
                                    "cat cat cat cattie cat";

    public static void main( String args[] ){
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
       Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); // get a matcher object
       int count = 0;

       while(m.find()) {
         count++;
         System.out.println("Match number "+count);
         System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
         System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
match number 1
start(): 0
end(): 3
match number 2
start(): 4
end(): 7
match number 3
start(): 8
end(): 11
match number 4
start(): 19
end(): 22
```

Comment: No, the group 0 is the whole match, the group 1 is the first capturing group, group 2 the second and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Read the javadoc of [`Matcher.group(int group)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

So, what you have is:

```
(.*)(\\d+)(.*)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ group 0
^^^^           group 1
    ^^^^^^     group 2
          ^^^^ group 3
```

Comment: How do I read it though with respect to the string pattern, like for group 2 why is the result 0?

Comment: @Nabz Because group 1 is *greedy*, so it matches `...QT300`, then stops there, in order for group 2 to have at least one digit, as required by the `+`. To make it non-greedy, change `(.*)` to `(.*?)`.